# Откуда появляются скобки при выводе значений из бд sqlite3 python3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

У меня возникла небольшая проблема.

```
@dp.message(F.text == '/start')
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    id_to_check = message.from_user.id
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    id_to_check = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute("select id from users where id=?", (id_to_check,))
    id_to_compare = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    universe_to_check = 0
    if id_to_compare != id_to_check and id_to_compare is not None:
        await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!\n\nПожалуйста, выберите вселенную, чтобы продолжить!', reply_markup=kb.universe_selection)
        print(id_to_check, id_to_compare[0])
        print('1')
    if id_to_compare[0] == id_to_check:
        print('2')
```

В итоге выводится вот это:

```
5089924791 (5089924791,)
1
```

Откуда-то в переменной, полученной из БД оказываются скобки, и сравнить значения не удается.

Тип id в бд sqlite3 NUMERIC

Код, который добавил это значение в бд:

```
async def register(Message, callback):
    user_id = callback.from_user.id
    username = callback.from_user.username
    status = 'active'
    extrapass = 'inactive'
    universe = 0
    money = 100
    cards = 0
    team = 0
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()

        sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO users
        (id, username, status, extrapass, money, cards, team, universe)
        VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"""

        data_to_insert = (user_id, username, status, extrapass, money, cards, team, universe)
        count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, data_to_insert)
        con.commit()
        print('[DEBUG]: SUCCESS')
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
    await menu_universe_dev(callback, Message)
```

Comment: Покажите код, который записал это значение в таблицу, а также `repr(id_to_compare)`

Comment: добавил код, который нужен был

Comment: И `repr(id_to_compare)` всё-таки тоже покажите

Comment: cursor.execute("select id from users where id=?", repr(id_to_check))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied. <-- ошибка

cursor.execute("select id from users where id=?", repr(id_to_check)) <-- добавил сюда. Возможно я не правильно понял вас(

Comment: Не понял что за дичь вы творите, просто через print посмотреть

Comment: И я спрашивал не про id_to_check, а про id_to_compare

Comment: print(repr(id_to_compare))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'id_to_compare' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: Ох, ну если вы даже не понимаете как работают переменные в питоне, то тут мне остаётся лишь отправить вас читать учебник